# How to show the checkbox in the react native app? When it is visible in android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using checkbox feature in react native from one of the community packages and it is visible in emulator but it does't show it in mobile. WHY?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in Checkbox tag

```
tintColors={{ true: '#F15927', false: 'black' }}
```

Now you can choose colour of your choice.